# How do I calculate age specific R^2 in R

Tags: r

I got demography dataset of swedish mortality from mortality.org which goes from year 1751 to 2011 and age 0 to 110. I've used the {demography} package to fit the Lee-carter model to this data from the period 1900 to 2011 and age 0 to 100. I now need to asses the fit of my estimates and intend to use the coefficient of determination to do so. My problem is now, that I need the age-specific R^2's for every age from 0 to 100 and only the overall R^2 are given when estimating the model. In other words, I need to find R^2 via the formular

R^2 (x)  = 1  -  ∑_x ( m(x,t) - predict{m(x,t)})^2 / ∑_x (m(x,t) - mean{m(x)})^2

for every x = 0,...,100. Here m(x,t) is the mortality rate a year t and age x, predict{m(x,t)} is Lee-carter prediction of m(x,t) and mean{m(x)} is the mean rate of mortality at age x. My code thus far:

```
#LEE-CARTER ANALYSIS OF SWEDISH MORTALITY

#Packages used in the mortality analysis
library(demography)
library(forecast)
library(lifecontingencies)

#Import of mortality Data:

Sweden <-hmd.mx(country="SWE", username="username@email.domin",password="password", label="Sweden")


#Fit of the LC model (in logarithmes) 

SWE.lcaM <- lca(Sweden, series="male", max.age=100, years = 1900:2011, interpolate = TRUE)
SWE.lcaF <- lca(Sweden, series="female", max.age=100, years = 1900:2011, interpolate = TRUE)

#Computation of R^2(x). The fitted values are in logarithms, so they need to be transformed by exp(). 
m_hat.f=exp(SWE.lcaF$fitted$y)
```

I do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Kamisra. It would help a lot if you'd provide sample (anonymized) data. (using `dput` preferably)

Comment: Are you needing help finding the formula for R^2?